# Animate one paragraph at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a div with several paragraphs inside of it. I want each of these paragraphs to fade in one after the other. I can do that with the following code. However, since I will have many more divs with many other paragraphs, each with their unique class names, I wonder if there is an easier way to achieve this, without keep copy-pasting the code, changing the class names each time.

```js
$('.line1').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(1000, function(){
  $('.line2').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $('.line3').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(1000, function(){
      $('.line4').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.line1, .line2, .line3, .line4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p class="line1">Text 01</p>
  <p class="line2">Text 02</p>
  <p class="line3">Text 03</p>
  <p class="line4">Text 04</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the class names be like the above, `line` followed by an ascending number? Or could those class names be anything?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The classes were going to have different names, but, if it helps getting to a more pratical solution, I can easily attach an ascending number to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names don't matter here, you can use `.line` or `.line{i}` or anything else, as long as there is an easy way to select all of them.

If you want different class names you could use `.div1 > p` in place of `.line` in the code.

If slight (+/- few milliseconds) innaccuracies aren't an issue, you could use setTimeout for this.

```js
$(".line").each(function (i) {
  $(this).css("opacity", 0);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
  }, 1000 * i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p class="line">Text 01</p>
  <p class="line">Text 02</p>
  <p class="line">Text 03</p>
  <p class="line">Text 04</p>
</div>
```

You can also use `.delay` instead of setTimeout.

```js
$(".line").each(function (i) {
  $(this).css("opacity", 0).delay(1000 * i).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p class="line">Text 01</p>
  <p class="line">Text 02</p>
  <p class="line">Text 03</p>
  <p class="line">Text 04</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly! Thanks for helping me out. Just one problem: For some reason, the lines are behaving as if they had a display of none instead of a visibility of hidden. What I mean is that the lines of text move each time a new one fades in, when one of the divs is vertically-centered on the page.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delay` to delay subsequent `fadeIn`s, like this:

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 4; ++n) {
    $(".line" + n).css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1000 * (n - 1)).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
for (var n = 1; n <= 4; ++n) {
    $(".line" + n).css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1000 * (n - 1)).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

```css
.line1, .line2, .line3, .line4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p class="line1">Text 01</p>
  <p class="line2">Text 02</p>
  <p class="line3">Text 03</p>
  <p class="line4">Text 04</p>
</div>
```

Or with any list of class names:

```
["line1", "line2", "line3", "line4"].forEach(function(cls, index) {
    $("." + cls).css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1000 * index).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Live Example:

```js
["line1", "line2", "line3", "line4"].forEach(function(cls, index) {
    $("." + cls).css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(1000 * index).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
.line1, .line2, .line3, .line4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p class="line1">Text 01</p>
  <p class="line2">Text 02</p>
  <p class="line3">Text 03</p>
  <p class="line4">Text 04</p>
</div>
```